# Meaning of the expression-"You got me"

Tags: word-usage, expressions

I was watching "Friends" the other day when this conversation popped up. I am a little bit confused with this expression-"You got me." What does it mean?

What does the speaker intend to say?

> Phoebe : I can’t believe you--did this.
>   So, what’s the deal with uh you and Joey?
>
> Ursula : Oh, right. He is so great. But that’s over.
>
> Phoebe : Does he know?
>
> Ursula : Who?
>
> Phoebe : Joey. You know, um, he’s really nutsy about you.
>
> Ursula : He is? Why?
>
> Phoebe : **You got me.**

Comment: Phoebe is saying;,"you know what I mean"!!

Comment: @Josh Can I substitute "You got me" every time I intend to say " you know what I mean" without changing the context of the sentence?

Comment: @Josh It *can* mean that in some contexts, as in 'you have apprehended my meaning correctly', but in *this* instance it means, 'you have stumped me', or 'I have no answer to that'. It can also mean, 'you fooled me' or 'you found me out' if someone has caught you out in some way.

Comment: Phoebe meant "you know what I mean", she would have said "you get me". "You got me"  never means, this, it always (in this context) means "I haven't a clue" and usually the person saying it is being heavily ironic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use this expression to say "I don't really know." Phoebe wants to say "I don't know why he's nutsy about you. You got me."

Comment: Its contradicting to what "Josh" in the comment section says.

Comment: @Cotton The expression could mean either, depending on the context and - very much - on the intonation. My interpretation, given the context above, is the same as the one suggested here.

Comment: @Cotton, I agree with Michael, from the context, this answer must be the right one.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. Ursula was Phoebe's evil twin; she did things like become a porn star using **Phoebe's** name, so Phoebe has no idea why Joey would like her.

Answer (score 1):

beware: in this instance "you got me" does *not* mean "you know what I mean".

Here it is a jocular way to say "I don't know the answer to that" -- as in: "you caught me out in a puzzle / riddle / contest of intellectual wit, by asking me a really difficult question."

The subtext here is that Phoebe is telling Ursula that she has no idea why Joey should find her attractive. It's Phoebe being catty.